# Snake with strange head

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

This snake was killed in graveyard Peshawar (Pakistan). I just wonder what is this? Is it a snake? Baby crying sounds were reportedly heard from graveyard in Peshawar after months of search the sounds of baby crying were identified and this snake was killed. I have a video. I just want to know what is this?

[image: photograph of dead horned snake]

Comment: It makes me sad that it was killed. Looks like Cerastes genus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerastes_(genus)

Comment: It seems like your dead snake is already [mentioned in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cerastes_cerastes&oldid=914970868#Distribution_and_habitat): "A member of this species [Cerastes cerastes] was reportedly found and killed by locals in urmar graveyard situated on border of Peshawar and Nowshera districts of Khyber Pakhtunkhwa province of Pakistan. The incident was reported along with a photo of the dead reptile in 'Aaj' Urdu language newspaper published from the provincial capital Peshawar on September 10, 2019."

Comment: Aren't _Cerastes_ spp. pretty much found in the Arabian peninsula and west?  Might this be in the genus _Pseudocerastes_, which is known to be found in Iran and Pakistan?

Comment: @mgkrebbs Perhaps. But the horns look more like Cerastes to me.

Answer (score 2):

The picture looks like it's from the Cerastes genus. It looks similar to a head shot of [*Cerastes Cerastes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cerastes_cerastes) (Saharan horned viper) shown on Wikipedia:

[image: Head shot of Cerastes Cerastes from Wikipedia, public domain]

In fact, the incident you describe is also [reported](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cerastes_cerastes&oldid=914970868#Distribution_and_habitat) in Wikipedia's *Cerastes Cerastes* article since it could be the first sighting in Pakistan. However, I sincerely (and respectfully) doubt that this snake was producing the "baby crying sounds". According to Wikipedia they produce a "rasping sound" when threatened.

I'm not sure that the specimen in your photograph is actually *Cerastes Cerastes* but the genus should be correct.